# Android GCM registartion id

Tags: android

What is the registration id in GCM, how to get the registration id for push notification?
Can youplease explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In code-

```
GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);//this line just initiates the process of registration and the onRegistered() of GCMBaseIntentService will be called when regId is assigned
String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
```

In Manifest-

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="package name" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Add the above in application tag.

Add some permissions as well-

```
<permission
android:name="com.vaayoo.android.pushnotify.shail.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.vaayoo.android.pushnotify.shail.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

This code works for me properly.